# ERROR org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator - HHH000351: Could not read or init a hi value

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Exception is occuring when trying to insert a blob record into oracle database using spring-data-jpa. the same exception is not throwing after restart the Tomcat server.

Please suggest what could be the reason for this?

Here is the Exception:

ERROR org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator  - HHH000351: Could not read or init a hi value
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:876) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3620) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator$1.execute(MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.java:168) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator$1.execute(MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.generate(MultipleHiLoPerTableGenerator.java:218) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:844) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:819) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:823) [hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:865) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.4.Final.jar:4.1.4.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) [spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy59.persist(Unknown Source) [na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.7.0_10]
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:863) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    ... 107 common frames omitted